# Multiple Domains Cannonicalisation

Tags: nginx

I have two domains I would like to canonicalise (remove www) and force on to https.

So http://www.domain.io => https://domain.io AND http://www.domain.ac => https://domain.ac

From what I've seen it would work something like this, but I can't find out how to extract the TLD

```
server_name domain.io domain.sh;
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
```

The live domains are both the same word, so could be matched like:

```
(domain)(\.ac|\.io)
```

Comment: You can use a regular expression in `server_name`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you leverage [server](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server) blocks:

```
server {
    server_name www.domain.io;
    return 301 https://domain.io$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name www.domain.sh;
    return 301 https://domain.sh$request_uri;
}
```

Such a configuration could easily be generated from a template with a configuration manager, as its the way recommended by nginx' creator, for performance/scalability reasons.

---

However, as Richard Smith suggested, you could also use regular expressions in the [server_name](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name) directive:

```
server {
    server_name ~^(?:www\.)?(?P<host_domain>.+)$;
    return 301 https://$host_domain$request_uri;
}
```

However, I would not personally recommend such a way and push for nginx' creator one.